# Mysql query based on category

Tags: mysql, database

Hi i have 3 tables as follow:

business:

```
business_id business_name cat_id sub_cat_id
  1           bz1           1      1001
  2           bz2           1      1005
  3           bz3           2      2001
  4           bz4           1      1001
```

business_category:

```
cat_id cat_name
1        Restaurant
2        Food
3        Travel
```

business_sub_category:

```
b_sub_cat_id b_subcat_name b_maincat_id
1001           Italian        1
1002           French         1
1003           Asian          1
2001           Bagels         2
```

Now my query seems not work well when i want to find business based on `b_subcat_name` using like. This are my query:

```
SELECT `b`.`business_name`, `b`.`cat_id`, `b`.`business_id`, `bc`.`cat_name`, `bsc`.`b_subcat_name`, `bsc`.`b_sub_cat_id` FROM `business` AS `b` INNER JOIN `business_category` AS `bc` ON b.cat_id = bc.cat_id INNER JOIN `business_sub_category` AS `bsc` ON b.sub_cat_id = bsc.b_sub_cat_id WHERE (bc.cat_name like 'italian%') OR (bc.cat_name like '%italian') OR (bc.cat_name = 'italian')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with 'not work well'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should using `b_subcat_name` in `WHERE` clause, because no `cat_name` has value contains `Italy`

Try to change this:

```
SELECT `b`.`business_name`, `b`.`cat_id`, `b`.`business_id`, `bc`.`cat_name`, `bsc`.`b_subcat_name`, `bsc`.`b_sub_cat_id` FROM `business` AS `b` INNER JOIN `business_category` AS `bc` ON b.cat_id = bc.cat_id INNER JOIN `business_sub_category` AS `bsc` ON b.sub_cat_id = bsc.b_sub_cat_id WHERE (bc.cat_name like 'italian%') OR (bc.cat_name like '%italian') OR (bc.cat_name = 'italian')
```

to

```
SELECT `b`.`business_name`, `b`.`cat_id`, `b`.`business_id`, `bc`.`cat_name`, `bsc`.`b_subcat_name`, `bsc`.`b_sub_cat_id` FROM `business` AS `b` INNER JOIN `business_category` AS `bc` ON b.cat_id = bc.cat_id INNER JOIN `business_sub_category` AS `bsc` ON b.sub_cat_id = bsc.b_sub_cat_id WHERE (bsc.b_subcat_name like 'italian%') OR (bsc.b_subcat_name like '%italian') OR (bsc.b_subcat_name = 'italian')
```